# Clustered columnstore index bad performance on insert

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

Good day everyone!

I have insert performance issues, when inserting data into a table with a clustered columnstore index.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    cal int NOT NULL,
    cod varchar(300) NULL
);
```

I am running a huge query in 100 batches. The amount of rows for the insert per batch is about 1.000.000.000.

Running the query and inserting into that table takes about 2h. Doing the same but inserting in a table without a clustered columnstore index takes 40 min.

Am I doing something wrong?
Any suggestions?

Thanks alot

Comment: Can you do the insert first, then apply your indexing? Having an index will slow down Insert speed. Also, the field `cod`, could you add these values only once into a separate table and reference them in table `T`? If you swapped this for an int, this should help with space and probably insert time. Inserting a billion rows is going to take some time. If this data is coming from a file, try reviewing `Bulk Insert` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, or `SqlBulkCopy` from C#.

Comment: The main reason for that index is that I do not have enough space on my drive. The table would be about 5 to 8 TB. With the index it's about 500GB

Comment: Yup that makes sense. Clustered columnstore indexes are great for compression, but that does come at the cost of Insert speed.